# In R, how to resample using cluster sampling with a defined number of clusters and observations within each cluster to prep for bootstrapping?

Tags: r, survey, resampling, statistics-bootstrap

I have data for 100 households that were randomly sampled from a larger community. I would now like to resample 10,000 grabs of 20 households from the original 100 household sample using different cluster sampling methods (i.e. 10 clusters of 2 households, 5 clusters of 4 households). Each cluster would consist of a randomly selected observation and the n observations immediately following it. Ex. For 10 clusters of 2 households, each cluster would consist of a randomly selected household and the household that immediately follows it in the dataset. For 5 clusters of 4 households, each cluster would consist of a randomly selected household and the 3 households that immediately follow it in the dataset.

I have been able to achieve the desired resampling output for 10,000 grabs of 20 households using simple random sampling with the following:

```
dat <- data.frame(hh_id = c(1:100), var = sample(1:200, 100, replace = T))
rs <- NULL
for(i in 1:10000){rs[i] = list(dat[sample(nrow(dat), 20, replace=TRUE),])}
```

How would I achieve the same output, but randomly selecting 10 clusters of 2 households (i.e. 20 households total per grab) instead of simple random sampling. I have looked at infer, sample, and resample packages, as well as others, and thoroughly looked through other posts here, but can't seem to find a solution that applies.

Ultimately, I will compare the variance of each sampling method from the 100 household mean to find a balance between accuracy and efficiency. If there is a shortcut to bootstrap all this directly, I would also be interested in that.

Comment: The function `boot` of the package `boot` has a parameter, `statistic`, which allows you to pass custom functions for your statistic(s) of interest. You may wanna check it out as `boot` is very flexible and practical when it comes to bootstrapping.

Comment: Thank you kindly, @Ozan147. I will explore using the statistic parameter in boot.

Comment: Thanks again, @Ozan147. Looking at this, it seems the `statistic` parameter works similarly to the parameter of the same name in `resample` and `bootstrap` functions. I'm still a bit stuck on how I would define the `statistic` parameter to randomly select row i and row i + 1. Might you have any guidance on how to do this?